# How to write Chinese value into Institution Name with fo-dicom?

Tags: dicom, fo-dicom

I was trying to write into DICOM tag (0008,0080) with Chinese words by fo-dicom. But found the Tag value just show the messy code in the result file. Please help to review it .

The C# code is below:

```
var file = DicomFile.Open(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\20D08F04"); 

//file.Dataset.Add(DicomTag.SpecificCharacterSet, "GB18030");
//file.Dataset.Add(DicomTag.SpecificCharacterSet, "ISO_IR 192");
//I already tried to specified the 0008,0005 with GBK and Utf-8. but it doesn't work. 
file.Dataset.Add(DicomTag.InstitutionName, "测试");

file.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test123.dcm");
```

The resulting file looks like blew in the DCMTK editor.

May anyone of you can help me?

[image]

I am sure the `DVTK` Dicom file editor support the Chinese character set.
Because there is another attribute `Patient's Name`'s value is Chinese. And can be viewed properly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default encoding in .NET *fo-dicom* is US-ASCII. It does not help if you set the *Specific Character Set* **after** you have opened the DICOM file, parsing is done in the open operation. *Specific Character Set*  only applies if it already set in the DICOM file.

What you can do is to set the "fallback encoding" to be used if *Specific Character Set* is not specified in the DICOM file, in the argument list of `DicomFile.Open`.

Try this for example:

```
var file = DicomFile.Open(fileName, DicomEncoding.GetEncoding("GB18030"));
```

And as @johnelemans pointed out in the comments, also verify that your viewer is capable of displaying the Chinese character set.

Comment: Hi Anders Gustafsson, It doesn't work. But your answer inspired me . I tried to add the tag with the specified encoding. And it works .

Comment: The code looks like : `DicomItem di = new DicomShortText(DicomTag.InstitutionName, DicomEncoding.GetEncoding("GB18030"), "磊一二");
                file.Dataset.Add(di);` Thanks.

Comment: Whether opening with the specified encoding or not doesn't matter.